# Installing jdk 7 on ubuntu 16.04 when java 8 is already present

Tags: java, java-7

I already have jdk 8 on my machine which is ubuntu 16.04. What i want to do 
is install jdk 7 now. But everything I have tried gives me an error and I am 
not able to run it. I have tried the following command I thought it will work but it failed:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

All the commands worked but final command gave me this error
download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Do i need to install java 8 and then first install java 7 and then 8 is that 
the problem?
Please let me know how to install java 7. I know how to switch between both the versions. Thank you in advance

Comment: Randomly deleting files from dpkg is a very Bad Idea TM. You have likely messed up the package manager's state and it cannot do anything useful for you any more. You will need to get the full error from dpkg and ask the nice folks at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) how to recover. If you're _very_ lucky it won't involve manually bootstrapping apt. Don't hold out high hopes however.

Comment: the forum for this kind of questions is [server fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you could install http://www.jenv.be/ to get both versions
Regards